# Inserting a node at the end of the list with the data of the first node

Tags: c++, insert, linked-list, copy

I am supposed to create a function to show the data in the first node and then making that node the last node in the list.  But I think an easier approach, would be to make the node after the first node the head of the list, and inserting a new node in the end of the list that has the data of the previous first node, I tried using different approaches but I am getting random question marks and symbols when doing so, I tried different methods but I can't really figure out what the problem is.

The code is attached below

```
  int places::showfirst()
  {
        node * current = head;
        node * temp = current -> next;
        node * temp2 = new node;
        cout << "The first place you visited is \n\n\t\n " << current -> place << endl;
        current->place = temporary;
        first = new char [strlen(temporary) +1];
        strcpy(first,temporary);

        while(current->next)
        {
              current = current -> next;
        }
        head = temp;
        current -> next = temp2;
        temp2 -> next = NULL;
        temp2->place = first;

        cout<<"THIS IS THE NEW LAST NODE " << temp2->place << endl;
        return 1;
  }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of creating a new node, why not just set next of the last node to the node you want to move to the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for memory re-allocation or de-allocation IMO. You can simply change the links and convert the existing head node to the last one:

```
node * current = head;
node * temp = current -> next;
cout << "The first place you visited is \n\n\t\n " << current -> place << endl;
while(current->next)
{
    current = current -> next;
}
current -> next = head;
head -> next = NULL;
head = temp;
```

Comment: After adding a temp2 after the line "current -> next = head" and assigning it to head the method worked, thank you so much!